# Parsing through a CSV file to add users

Tags: linux, unix

I'm having trouble parsing through a CSV file to add users.

I wrote a small script to add a list of 1000 users.
I'm trying to sort my users into specific servers, so what I'm trying to do at the moment is grab lines 1-299 , all the users by gender. I would have one server with all male users and one with all female users. 
Additionally I have to add a comments with their first and last names .
CSV is formatted:

```
af1001,afeni,freeborn,f,May 7 1994,IR_Iran,5,Centre_back,Nizhny_Novgorod_Stadium
md1707,melaya,dion,f,October 16 1996,Colombia,13,Sweeper,Mordovia_Arena
lm1540,leondre,metzner,m,September 27 1985,Germany,5,Centre_midfield,Kazan_Arena
jo1304,juelz,orengo,m,September 27 1999,France,23,Goalkeeper,Ekaterinburg_Arena
```

what I have so far :

```
head -n 299 users.csv | grep -w f| cut -d ',' -f1 |  while read line; do sudo useradd “$line“ ; done
```

Of course this only adds the users but not the comment of their names. I tried the following:

```
head -n 299 selli049.csv | grep -w f| cut -d ',' -f1,2,3|  while read line; do sudo useradd -c “$line” $f1 ; done
```

But that didn't work. I am pretty new to this so looking for helpful tips. Thanks.

Comment: [Import users from CSV file](https://askubuntu.com/q/633695), [Write a script to create users with pre-defined passwords](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85642/56041), [Linux Shell script to add a user with a password to the system](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html), [Need help with looping through a csv file and creating users](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/1zlwdv/bash_need_help_with_looping_through_a_csv_file/), etc.

Comment: Why have you tagged it `PowerShell` when you aren't using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Set a target gender
target_gender='f'

# Cat your csv file and set the while separator to a comma, then assign each field to a variable
cat users.csv | while IFS="," read username first last gender date country number position field; do
  # If the gender matches the target add a user and set their comment to first and last name
  if [[ "${gender}" == "${target_gender}" ]]; then
    # -c adds a comment
    sudo useradd ${username} -c "${first} ${last}"
  fi
done
```

Additional reading:

[What is IFS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184867/292493)

[useradd manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)